# How does Azure Signal R handle Application Server scaling?

Tags: signalr, azure-signalr

We have an existing web service that we are modifying such that when certain events happen within the service then they can be published to users that are interested.  We are using Azure Signal R Service as our mechanism for relaying messages from our service to interested users.  Currently, our architecture looks like this:
[image]

- Our Signal R application server has only **one hub** and we are currently running three instances of the application server.  I have labeled these *Hub Instance 01*, *Hub Instance 02*, and *Hub Instance 03* in the diagram above.
- Each instance of our existing web service opens one connection to the Azure Signal R service.  After reading the [Azure SignalR Service internals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-internals) docs I have come to understand that each client connection to the Azure Signal R service goes through a one-time mapping to an application server (or Hub Instance in this case).  In the diagram I have modeled that by showing a colored link coming from either the existing web service instance or a user and another link of the same color and style coming out of the Azure Signal R service and into a single Hub Instance.

Our primary concern is that the connection from the existing web service instance into the Azure Signal R service (*the solid green and solid blue links in the diagram*) could become saturated if we're trying to send too many events.  Our plan to mitigate that concern was to open multiple connections from each web service instance to the Azure Signal R service.  Then, within our code we would simply round-robin through each of the connections as we send messages.

Our concern with that approach is that we don't know how those connections to the Azure Signal R service are going to be mapped to Hub Instances.  We could end up in a situation like the one below, where one or two Hub Instances end up taking the brunt of our traffic.
[image]

In this diagram we can see:

- Each instance of the existing web service has opened multiple connections to the Azure Signal R service.  Unfortunately, *Hub Instance 01* and *Hub Instance 03* have been assigned the majority of those connections.  That means that they'll be taking the brunt of our traffic and will eventually start to run hot.

This leads me to the following questions:

1. Is there anything we can do in our existing web service to make sure that the connections we establish to the Azure Signal R service are evenly spread out across the Hub Instances?
2. What can we do if one of our Hub Instances starts running hot?  It seems like just adding another Hub Instance isn't going to be helpful because only new clients will be assigned to that instance.  Is there a way to have the Azure Signal R service re-balance connections when a new Hub Instance comes online?
3. How are client connections affected if an application server instance goes down (i.e. for deploying updates)?  Are the client connections terminated and then the client is supposed to reconnect?
4. Within the Azure Signal R service, how are connections balanced if the Signal R Service cluster itself needs to scale up or down?

Answer (score 0):

We're facing a similiar issue, and from what I've read in [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr) they suggest incorporating a backplane using Redis or Service Bus into the architecture to manage the connections.